# ANACONDA NAVIGATOR not lauching

Tags: python, anaconda, navigator

As soon as I click on anaconda navigator it does not respond. There are no warnings or errors.  I did not click on anything. Please help. I just purchased a python course from an online platform and they asked me to use anaconda navigator. Please help.

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: which platform?

Comment: We're going to need more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

First try launching anaconda-navigator from the anaconda prompt. If that works, do the below.

This happened to me and this is how I resolved it.

1. I uninstalled all python versions (Anaconda and Normal Python).
2. Reinstall the 64 bit version of anaconda (if you also want the normal python, install the normal python 64 bit first and then the anaconda).
3. Try launching the anaconda-navigator now.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if you fulfill these requirements:

Windows 10 x86_64 or newer
macOS 10.14+, 64-bit
Ubuntu 14+/Centos7+, 64-bit
The most current installation of Navigator also supports Python versions 2.7 and 3.5+.

Moreover, try this one `conda update anaconda-navigator`.
Here you might face issue with `conda` if navigator is not launched.